# Fastest Algorithm for Shortest Paths with negative values?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I'm currently using Bellman Ford algorithm to find the shortest paths with negative value. Is there any faster algorithm that would outperform Bellman Ford for finding shortest paths with negative values?

Comment: I can only give you the Wikipedia article on that mater: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Improvements of course this also calls for the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ And a warning: "Debugging something is twice as hard as writing it in the first place. So if you wrote something at the top of your skill, you will never be able to debug it."

Comment: When you mentioned Bellman Ford and asking for faster solution, what is your current running time and what you expect to be faster

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I have a graph with 50+ vertexes and theres an edge from each to each one. What i meant by faster is also for example if there is a algorithm that could process all of it differently which would improve time

Comment: @Nicholas: for a randomly generated fully connected directed graph with randomly generated weights of 50 vertices the code in my answer takes with interpreted python about 1-2ms in non-degenerate case and 50ms in a degenerate case (negative sum loop). The time for the naive solution on the same graph is about 50ms. I'd expect a native code implementation to be about 50-100 times faster...

Answer (score 1):

A simple improvement is to only check for "active" nodes instead of iterating on all of them as the naive implementation does.
The reason is that if a node didn't lead to improvements on any of its neighbors and didn't change value in last iteration there is no need to redo the computation again (it will still produce no improvements).

Pseudocode (Python, actually):

```
A = set([seed])
steps = 0
while len(A) > 0 and steps < number_of_nodes:
    steps += 1
    NA = set()
    for node in A:
        for nh in neighbours(node):
            x = solution[node] + weight(node, nh) 
            if x < solution[nh]:
                # We found an improvement...
                solution[nh] = x
                pred[nh] = node
                NA.add(nh)
    A = NA
```

`A` is the "active" node set, where an improvement was found on last step and `NA` is the "next-active" node set that will need to be checked for improvements on next iteration.

Initially the solution is set to `+Infinity` for all nodes except the `seed` where the solution is 0. Initially only the `seed` is in the "active" set.
Note that in case of negative-sum loops reachable from the seed the problem has no "minimum path" because you can get the total as low as you want by simply looping; this is the reason for the limit on the "steps" value.

If when coming out of the loop `A` is not empty then there is no solution to the minimum cost problem (there is a negative-sum loop and you can lower the cost by simply looping).